# Change Android's default programs?

Tags: android

If i'm developing an alternative Android SMS application, is there any way to replace the default sms application with my, so that my app receives the incoming sms message?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the default SMS app from receiving the message? My understanding is that both programs will "receive" the SMS message if you have multiple SMS applications installed.

Comment: hmmm ok if the both receive, but can i make my app some sort of "priority", so user don't get two notifications for one sms?

Comment: I don't think you have any control over that. I've used "alternative" SMS apps before and generally I have to turn off notifications in the default one as the user in order to prevent this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enforce your app on the users. As Corey mentioned users will have to switch off sms notifications in the default app to not getting the notification twice.

Answer (score 4):

you just have to set a higher priority for your broadcast receiver like this. For example 100

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then you have to call abortBroadcast(); when you want it to stop if you dont want it to propagate. This only works for orderedbroadcasts.